# Muestre que un mapeo continuo y sobre no necesariamente es cerrado

Tags: general-topology

Dada la función proyección del plano al eje $X$ 
$\pi_{1} :\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} (x,y)\mapsto x$ 
La función anterior es claramente continua y sobre 
Para ver que no es cerrada considero el conjunto 
$A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: xy = 1 \}$ 
Se que A es cerrado pero no se como demostrarlo. 
Tampoco se como demostrar que la imagen de $A$ no es cerrada. 
$\pi_{1}(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}:  \forall y \in \mathbb{R},\, xy = 1\}$

---

The projection map
$\pi_{1} :\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} (x,y)\mapsto x$
is obviously continuous and onto. To see that $\pi_1$ is not a closed map I want to consider the set
$A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: xy = 1 \}$.

I know $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I don't know how to prove it. I don't know either how to show that the image of $A$ under $\pi_1$ is not a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To check $A$ is closed use that the limit of every convergent sequence of points of $A$ is in $A$. $pi(A)$ is the real line minus $0$ so it is not closed.

Comment: The set $\pi_1(A)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ which is not closed ($0$ is an accumulation point of $\pi_1(A)$ and it is not in $\pi_1(A)$. As for why the set $A$ is closed, consider a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\in A$ such that $(x_n,y_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_0,y_0)$, Show that $x_0y_0=1$.

Comment: Note that $\pi_1$ *is* an open map, so here we have quotient map that is not closed. Examples the other way round (continnuous, closed, but not open) also exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely general technique for proving that a set is closed is using the following theorem:

Theorem: let $f : A \to B$ be continuous and $K \subseteq B$ be closed. Then $f^{-1}(K) = \{x \in A | f(x) \in K\}$ is closed.

In this case, the continuous function is the multiplication function $(x, y) \to x \cdot y$ and the closed set is $\{1\}$.

As for the image, consider $\pi_1[A] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | \exists y \in \mathbb{R} ( xy = 1 )\}$. This is exactly $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$, which *not* closed while $A$ is.

Comment: I replaced open by the more relevant "not closed".